# Free energy variations

Tags: continuum-mechanics, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

In a paper, I found this:

$\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{r})$ is called molecular field and is defined as the variation field of the Frank free energy functional $F_{d}$ with respect to the polarization field $\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r})$:

$F_{d}=\int d\mathbf{r}\left(\frac{\alpha(\rho)}{2}|\mathbf{p}|^{2}+\frac{\beta}{4}|\mathbf{p}|^{4}+\frac{K}{2}(\partial_{\alpha}p_{\beta})(\partial_{\beta}p_{\alpha})-v_{1}\frac{\rho-\rho_{0}}{\rho_{0}}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p}+\frac{\lambda}{2}|\mathbf{p}|^{2}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p}\right)$

$$\mathbf{h}=-\frac{\delta F_{d}}{\delta\mathbf{p}}=\left[\alpha(\rho)+\beta|\mathbf{p}|^{2}\right]\mathbf{p}+K\nabla^{2}\mathbf{p}+v_{1}\nabla\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{0}}\right)-\lambda\nabla|\mathbf{p}|^{2}-\lambda\mathbf{p}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p})$$

Now, could you explain what kind of calculation was performed here, and how can I remake it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative):

$F_d[{\bf p}] = \int  \mathrm d\boldsymbol{r}\ f( \boldsymbol{r}, {\bf p}(\boldsymbol{r}), \nabla\cdot {\bf p}(\boldsymbol{r}) )$

$\frac{\delta F_d}{\delta {\bf p}(\boldsymbol{r})} := \frac{\partial f}{\partial {\bf p}} - \nabla \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial\nabla\cdot {\bf p}},$

although something's weird with your signs. Your ${\bf p}$ also has several components, which makes it slightly more trickier - but you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, and if $f=f(r,p(r),\nabla\cdot p(r), \nabla\times p(r))$?

Comment: @usumdelphini: Eventually $f$ must be scalar. Of course. There is no significant difference between grad and curl within $f$, you should view it as containing all components $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}f$. Componentwise functional derivative is straightforward and described in the beginning of the article. It's essentially just like normal differentiation, you do it in all directions and collect the terms.

Comment: If I understand, it becomes $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_{i}}-\sum\partial_{j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\partial_{j}p_i}$, is that true?

Comment: @usumdelphini: Yes, for each or the $p_i$'s. This is what links to "[note 5]" in the wikipedia article. In fact, it's even more general there, as the functional integrand there is allowed to have higher derivatives in $p$ than only the first one $\nabla {\bf p}$.